# Multiple items delete from firebase database using recycler vew

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I made employee registration app in android studio using firebase database backend, but in case of remove employee i don't able to delete multiple or selected items.

I want to made Recycler View with Check boxes for delete selected employees from firebase database.

How i do it?

Comment: If you are interested to remove items using a RecyclerView left/right swipe, I think this **[article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf)** will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add Recycler Item Select Listener then pass the selected items to your Recycler Adapter temporarily and then run a DataSnapshot loop to delete each selected item.

simple, hope that would help you.